# FOR more than four decades vs [X]more than four decade?

Tags: prepositions

I read an aritlce saying:

> We are so proud to represent Queen and are thrilled to see the song
>   still inspiring new fans around the world **more than four decades
>   after its release**.

from [this site](https://www.universalmusic.com/queens-iconic-bohemian-rhapsody-becomes-streamed-song-20th-century/).

I am wondering why there is no 'for'(like 'for more than four decades after its release'). I thought 'decades' is noun so it needs preposition to make prepositional phrase such as for two decades, for two years. Is the 'more than four decades' prepositional phrase so that it modifies the prepositional phrase      'after its release'?

Comment: _For more than four decades_ means ‘during a period that lasts/lasted more than four decades’. So, for example, Queen Elizabeth II has been queen of the UK for more than four decades. Given that the sentence you quote refers to a specific point in time (right now), what makes you believe that you need to add _for_ here? _More than four decades_ is a noun phrase, yes, and it needs a preposition to become a prepositional phrase – but what makes you think it has to be or become a prepositional phrase to begin with?

Answer (score 1):

It is because the sentence's verb is *proud to represent* and they want to 
say that that action happened at the moment located *more than four decades
after its release*, instead of all along the interval of time delimited by
*more than four decades after its release*.

Comment: We set mentions in italic, not as computer code. Please do not use markdown for computer code to indicate you are mentioning a word.